# How to get an large file into Azure Storage Account by URL?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

I am trying to copy a file from URL into an Azure Storage Account.

Microsoft has a doc for exactly this use case with Azure Data Factory (ADF) via [these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-http?tabs=data-factory). I tried using a test file from [here](https://speed.hetzner.de/) (or anywhere for that matter).

In ADF, I set up the Copy activity with an HTTP Linked Service pointing to one of the .bin files in above URL using a GET request and Binary copy (as is file copy). I am able to hit the Test Connection button on both the source URL and the destination Linked Service that points to an Azure Storage Account and it succeeds.

However, after running the ADF pipeline, the resulting file is a file with a name that appears to be a random gui and is corrupted (the contents is garbled).

What am I missing here? Is there some other way to load a giant file by URL to an Azure Storage container?

Comment: Please edit your question to include all relevant details, such as what, exactly, you're doing when trying to retrieve a file; where you're copying it to (and how you configured your activity to copy a file); what specific errors/issues you're having. Currently, as written, you've only provided a link to an external document. All details need to be in your question; nobody should have to visit another site to learn what you're doing.

Comment: Added more words. Ultimately the question remains the same.